# Defaulting an updateview action in django form under a def post

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

Working with another coder on a project.  His change stopped the `UpdateView` on some forms from saving edits.  I realized why.... he defined a

```
def post
```

which works for the case he was working on, but needs an else action that just does a default update.  I am not sure how to do this when he `UpdateView` isn't doing it all automagically.

The code to the `UpdateView`:

```
class ProviderUpdateView(UpdateView):                                                                                             
  model = Provider                                                                                                                
  form_class = ProviderForm                                                                                                       
  provider_form_class = ProviderForm                                                                                                       
  provider_term_form_class = ProviderTermForm                                                                                                       
  template_name = 'ipaswdb/provider/provider_form.html'                                                                           
  success_url = '/ipaswdb/provider/'                                                                                               

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProviderUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    provider = context['object'] 
    context['provider_id'] = provider.id
    prov = Provider.objects.get(pk=provider.id)

    #print "provider: ",
    #print prov
    #print "provider terminated: ",
    #print prov.is_terminated

    if prov.is_terminated:
      provider_form = ProviderFormView(instance=prov)
      context['readonly'] = True 
    else:
      print("NOT TERMINATED SO LETS DO THIS")
      provider_form = ProviderForm(instance=prov)
      context['readonly'] = False 

    context['provider_form'] = provider_form 

    provider_term_form = ProviderTermForm()
    context['provider_term_form'] = provider_term_form 

    ### Get the list of GroupLocations, but remove the current one this provider is associated with
    ### I just need the grouplocation id and the name
    #grplocs = GroupLocationProvider.objects.filter(

    return context


  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #print self.request.POST.keys()
    #print self.request.POST.values()
    print("Posting...")
    if self.request.POST.has_key('terminate'):
      provider = Provider.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
      form = ProviderTermForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        print "Terminating Provider: ",
        print provider

        provider_term = ProviderTerm()

        provider.is_terminated = True
        provider.save()

        ### Update the term fields
        provider_term.provider = provider
        provider_term.old_id = provider.id
        provider_term.term_date = form.cleaned_data['term_date']
        provider_term.term_comment = form.cleaned_data['term_comment']
        provider_term.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

I know I need an else to this statement in the post:

```
if self.request.POST.has_key('terminate'):
```

I am just not sure what the just do your regular thing' is in the `UpdateView`.  I tested my hypothesis that his code broke the ability to edit and save a provider cause I removed the def post completely, and all worked well with the `UpdateView` automagic. Since we are overriding? the `def post` it seems to me we have to handle the regular update ourselves, just not sure how that looks.

Comment: `else: super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: If you want to make default `post` method on `else` statement then try; `else: super(ProviderUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: that did it, wow thanks, i knew this was simple just didn't know what to call.  super.  how easy was that. thanks!